# Use ORDER BY clause after WHERE in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with an `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE [Design]
SET [IsLocked] = 0
WHERE (SELECT [d].[DesignKey]
       FROM [project] AS [P]
       INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
       INNER JOIN [design] AS [d] ON [pd].[DesignKey] = [d].[DesignKey]
       WHERE [P].[Name] = @ProjectName
       ORDER BY [D].[DesignKey] DESC) = @DesignKey
```

But when I try to run it I get this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

What I'm doing wrong? Why can't I use `ORDER BY` in subquery? How can I solve it?

Comment: The `order by` clause in the sub query would not have any effect, even if it worked.

Comment: The question is why would you use `ORDER BY` in a subquery in an update???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I can't use ORDER BY in subquery?

Because it's pointless, unless you specify a `TOP` or `OFFSET`. Why does it matter what order the subquery is in if you're not using either of those qualifiers?

It *seems* like you want the *first* result in the subquery, which does make sense, but you need to add a `TOP 1` to the subquery:

```
(SELECT TOP 1
...
ORDER BY ...) = @DesignKey
```

or use `MAX`:

```
(SELECT
   MAX([d].[DesignKey])
   ...
 ) = @DesignKey
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update an only top record of the subquery with order by clause. Use below subquery.

```
    (SELECT LAST 1
    ...
    ORDER BY ASC) = @DesignKey

Else if you need to update all the subquery records , use below query

UPDATE [Design]
SET [IsLocked] = 0
WHERE [DesignKey] 
in
(SELECT distinct [d].[DesignKey]
FROM [project] AS [P]
INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [pd].ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN [design] AS [d] ON [pd].[DesignKey] = [d].[DesignKey]
WHERE [P].[Name] = @ProjectName
ORDER BY [D].[DesignKey] DESC)
```